# How to use await async in firebase cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, asynchronous, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I've built a couple of cloud functions in nodejs 6 and now i want to use `await`. How do I do that? How can I upgrade to node 8? I don't want to shift to typescript.

I've tried adding `"engines": {"node": "8"}` to package.json but it changed nothing.

This is a test cloud function I made:

```
exports.awaittest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res)=>{
    ref = await admin.database().ref("/something/");
    res.send(ref)
})
```

when I try to deploy it (with package.json edited), I get this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at getUserFunction (/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:413:24)
!  functions[awaittest]: Deployment error.
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/index.js:59
exports.awaittest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res)=>{
                                                    ^
```

How do I upgrade to node8? I already have 6 functions deployed in node6.

Comment: https://node.green/  ... you have to upgrade. Simply npm a upgrade to node or install it directly (windows)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the version of the CLI you're using, and proof that your function deployed to node 8 (it will be in the output).  Also you should know that TypeScript is a strict superset of JavaScript, so all your JavaScript will just keep working if you just copy it over to TS.

Comment: I am not with my laptop rn but I have ensured that all my tools and framework are up-to-date. If you think I should shift to typescript, please do tell me how to migrate my project to ts.

Comment: You also need to be using Node.js 8 on your local machine, or the CLI will have parse errors when trying to extract trigger information from your code.

Comment: Can you make sure adding `"engines": {"node": "8"}` into `functions/package.json`, not `package.json`?

Comment: I checked and I have node 7.6.0 installed on my pc. For that sake I added "engines": {"node": "7.6.0"} instead of 8 to functions/package.json . Still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it in the `functions/.eslintrc.json` directory by changing the following:

```js
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 6
}

// to

"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 2017
}
'''
```

Comment: I added engines node 8 but still got same error.
![image](https://ibb.co/bbz1P75).

Comment: did you remove older functions in google cloud console. You gotta do this in GCC, not firebase.

Comment: thank you, i found the solution, just place this to the .eslintrc.json

`"parserOptions": {"ecmaVersion": 2017},`