# Using async/await in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

My app.post throws the following error when trying to firebase deploy: Parsing error: Unexpected token =>
What is the problem and how to fix it? I am totally new to node.js and Javascript.
Normally I am writing Swift but I need this piece of code for my Cloud Functions.

I want to use a http request to get back the users in my users collection like

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("users").get();

  let users = [];
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    let id = doc.id;
    let data = doc.data();

    users.push({ id, ...data });
  });
```

but it also throws the error Unexpected token => when trying to deploy.
Can someone please help how to fix the problem?

Thank you!

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
admin.initializeApp();

const app = express();

app.use(cors({origin: true}));

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("hello world");
});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    // Do something here
  });

// Expose Express API as a single Cloud Function:
exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

app.get works perfect, app.post does not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the arrow function isn't working, but try just doing this:

```
app.get("/", async function(req, res) {
  await new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res,2000));
  res.send("hello world");
});
```

If it works, substitute `await new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res,2000))` with whatever asynchronous code you are using. If it doesn't work, then you need to make sure that you should check your node version.

Comment: I've been on Node.js version 14.16.0 and I did not see there was an error when installing dependencies, where it tells me I need node 12. so I downloaded node 12 and now everything works fine. thanks for your help

Comment: here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53384916/how-to-use-await-async-in-firebase-cloud-function